# C++ ifstream exception masks for C#

Tags: c#, c++, ios, exception, ifstream

How would I convert this line from C++ to C#?

```
std::ifstream in;
in.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit); //*THIS LINE*
```

According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/), the previous line of code sets a new exception mask for the stream and clears any current error state flags. I'm also guessing that it is the "second form" of `std::ios::exceptions` from the page linked above.

Because of my inexperience with C#'s `FileStream` class, I've been getting pretty confused due to the lack of anything similar.

Comment: For C++ only: streams throwing exceptions are bad (my opinion). For C++ interacting with c++/clr it becomes worse - you have to translate C++ exceptions to C++/clr exceptions, while crossing the boundary from C++ to C++/clr

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not using C++/clr. I just want to accomplish the same thing with C#.

Comment: Are you trying to have FileStream throw exceptions on IO errors? Because that's the default behaviour. Both Read and Write methods will throw an IOException if an IO error occurs.

Comment: I've expanded on my statement in an answer. If you found my comment useful, I would be grateful if you could mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`FileStream.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FileStream.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) methods will throw an [`IOException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception(v=vs.110).aspx) should any underlying I/O error occur. This is default behaviour.

Unlike C++, exception throwing is the expected form of error handling in C#. Because exceptions were a part of .NET from the beginning, there is none of [the contention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180268/why-are-c-stl-iostreams-not-exception-friendly) surrounding use of exceptions with streams as there is with C++.

Most - if not all - of the .NET framework standard libraries will throw exceptions in exceptional states. The only exception I can think of is when using the [Try-Parse pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is pretty explicit about the expected behaviour.