# Clarification on a basic behavior of cin in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am curious why `cin` behaves in the following way. I think I might have 
some misunderstanding about its behavior.

Consider this simple code. This code is asks for some input to be entered, all of which is printed out in the last statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  cout << "Please enter your input: " ;
  int a=3, b=87; // initialized to some random integers
  string s = "Mary" ; // initialized to a random string
  cin >> a ;
  cin >> b ;
  getline(cin,s);
  cout << "You entered the following " << a << "  " << b << "  " << s << endl;
  return 0;  
}
```

Now if the input is `12 34 cat` the output is `12 34  cat`
This is expected.

However if the input is `cat 23 dog` the output is `0 87  Mary`.

Here is why I think this is unexpected:

`cin >> a` should fail since `cat`cannot be converted into an integer. However, `a` gets replaced with what I presume is a garbage value.

Now since the second number of the input is an integer 23, `cin >> b` must succeed. Yet this operation seems to fail, and `b` continues to retain its original value unlike what happened to `a`.

Similarly `getline` fails to place the string `<space>dog` into the string `s`
which continues to retain its original value of `Mary`.

My questions are the following.

1. Does the failure of some `cin` operation mandate the failure of *all*
   subsequent `cin` operations using the `>>` operator or the `getline` function.
2. Why did the failure of the first `cin` operation change the value of `a`
   whereas the initial values of `b` and `s` were unchanged?

Comment: It's an error to read string input into an int. Check the state of `cin` and you'll see the fail flag is set. The proper way to get input is to get all as a string and then attempt to parse. Also, be careful when you mix `getline()` and `cin` as you are, because `cin` leaves the newline character in the buffer, which `getline` can erroneously grab.

Comment: There is only one interesting point in this question: Why is `a` becoming `0` although the input is failing. (The other are blocked, due to that fail state)

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180268/why-are-c-stl-iostreams-not-exception-friendly). Kind of usefull too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Does the failure of some cin operation mandate the failure of all subsequent cin operations using the >> operator or the getline function.

Yes. Your code expects to read the input value in exactly that order

```
cin >> a ; // 1st integer value
cin >> b ; // 2nd integer value
getline(cin,s); // string value
```

Giving it a input like

```
cat 23 dog
```

leads to setting `fail()` state on `cin` when trying to read the 1st `int` value, and none of the following `operator>>()` calls will succeed.

---

> *`cin >> a` should fail since `cat`cannot be converted into an integer. However, `a` gets replaced with what I presume is a garbage value.*

It's no garbage value but well defined, see the reference citation below.

> Now since the second number of the input is an integer 23, `cin >> b` must succeed. Yet this operation seems to fail, and `b` continues to retain its original value unlike what happened to `a`.

No this assumption is wrong, as mentioned `cin` is in `fail()` state at this point, and parsing further input is skipped at all.

You have to call `clear()` after each `operator>>()` call, to be sure the input will by parsed:

```
cin >> a ; // 1st integer value
cin.clear();
cin >> b ; // 2nd integer value
cin.clear();
getline(cin,s); // string value
```

---

> 2. Why did the failure of the first cin operation change the value of a whereas the initial values of b and s were unchanged?

Because the reference of [`std::basic_istream::operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) says

> *"If extraction fails, zero is written to value and `failbit` is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and `failbit` flag is set. <sup>(since C++11)</sup>"*

Comment: Your "solution" implies that `cin` skips over invalid input,but it doesn't.  If the input is "cat 23 dog", then `a=0, b=0,s="cat"`, which I think the OP would find unexpected.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Actually, `s="cat 23 dog"`

Comment: @MooingDuck I tried to improve my answer to explain the particular behavior.

Answer (score 8):

> Does the failure of some cin operation mandate the failure of all
>   subsequent cin operations using the >> operator or the getline
>   function.

Yes. Until you clear the error with `cin.clear()`. Also, when an extraction fails, the characters are left in the buffer, so if you try to read the same type again, it will fail again.

> Why did the failure of the first cin operation change the value of a
>   whereas the initial values of b and s were unchanged?

Because (since C++11), it is defined to change the value to 0 in case of failed extraction from a (previously) valid stream. Before C++11, it would have been left unchanged. For a stream in an error state, the operation does nothing, which is why `b` and `s` are unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cin.good()` function or shorthand notation `if(cin)` as said by @AndyG to check the state of `cin` object. variable `a` is of type `int` then how can you & why are you inputting string? So, it gives unexpected output for variable `a`.

Comment: `cin` has an implicit conversion to `bool` so `if(cin)` is adequate.